# how to change greeting textView i.e, Good morning or Good night in Android studio using Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

[image: Here is the screenshot of my app]

I am making an app in kotlin language. I want to change that Good morning textview to good evening when time is between 4 pm to 8pm and goodnight when time is in range of night time and agin to good morning when time pasts 12 am.

how can i do it in kotlin?

Comment: What did you try yourself and what hurdles did you encounter?

Comment: i really dont know how to do it . i have seen calendar class and time but that code is in java and then the main problem is how do i find that  that particular time is in range of time set by me for particular greeting text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply get hour like this:

```
val currentHour = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR)
```

And set text, based on the hour.

```
text.text = if(currentHour > 20 && currentHour < 4) "Good evening" else "Good morning"
```

Answer (score 0):

//Set greeting

```
    val greetingtext = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.greeting)
    val currentHour = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR)
    greetingtext.text = if(currentHour < 13 && currentHour < 4) "Good afternoon!" else "Good morning!"
    greetingtext.text = if(currentHour < 18 && currentHour < 18 ) "Good evening!" else "Good evening!"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

#### First:

you need to get the **HOUR_OF_DAY** from Calendar instance it's from 0 to 23

```
val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
val currentHour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
```

#### Then:

you need to check, if current time between 0 to 11 which is 12 AM to 11:59 AM, so it's ***morning*** else it's ***evening***

```
// Set the greeting based on the time
val greeting: String = if (currentHour in 0..11) {
    "Good morning"
} else {
    "Good evening"
}
```